# Share link does not include link for LinkedIn

Tags: feature-request, sharing

I wanted to share a question on LinkedIn, but in the *share* link there are only options to share on Google+, Facebook and Twitter.

I think it would be useful if LinkedIn is also in that list.

Comment: You can still manually share it by copying the link you get and posting it on LinkedIn (or any other site for that matter).

Comment: so do we can on google+, twitter and facebook :)

Comment: The real question is why they still have a Google+ link. Does anyone still actually use Google+?